# How can I define type-level list indexing amenable to proof?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-families

```hs
{-# language GADTs, KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeApplications, TypeOperators,
    TypeFamilies, PolyKinds, UndecidableInstances, RankNTypes, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
```

I would like to index a type-level list with a type-level `Nat`:

```hs
type family Index (xs :: [a]) (k :: Nat) where
    Index (x:xs) 0 = x
    Index (x:xs) k = Index xs (k - 1)
```

Note that I'm using `GHC.TypeLits.Nat` instead of, say, `data Nat = Z | S Nat`, as the actual parameter comes from an `SNat` and I would like to avoid storing numbers in unary at runtime.

This definition works fine for concrete types:

```
*Main> :k! Index [Int, Double, String] 1
Index [Int, Double, String] 1 :: *
= Double
```

However, in some of my functions, I need to prove that `Index v n ~ Index (a:v) (n+1)`. GHC cannot solve this by itself:

```hs
prf :: Index v n -> Index (a:v) (n + 1)
prf x = x
```

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Index (a : v) (n + 1)’
                  with actual type ‘Index v n’
      NB: ‘Index’ is a non-injective type family
    • In the expression: x
      In an equation for ‘prf’: prf x = x
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: Index v n (bound at Minimal.hs:11:5)
        prf :: Index v n -> Index (a : v) (n + 1)
          (bound at Minimal.hs:11:1)
```

Is it possible to prove this type equality? If not, what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to prove this type equality?

Unfortunately, you're out of luck on actually *proving* anything here, as far as I'm aware.  You can perform arithmetic on `Nat`s, but GHC doesn't actually *know* anything about them.  As a simple example of this:

```
> :k! forall n. n + 1 - 1
forall n. n + 1 - 1 :: Nat
= (n + 1) - 1
```

In other words, GHC can't tell that `n + 1 - 1 ~ n`.  From that alone, your definition, which uses `+` while your type family uses `-` won't work.  But, you're actually in even more trouble.  Because you're using GHC's `Nat` and not something unary, you've written your type family as a closed type family:

```hs
type family Index (xs :: [a]) (k :: Nat) where
    Index (x:xs) 0 = x
    Index (x:xs) k = Index xs (k - 1)
```

In order for GHC to use the second case, it has to know, without a doubt, that the second argument is not `0`.  But remember, GHC doesn't really know anything about the "math" used on `Nat`.  For instance, it doesn't know that `n + 1` won't ever end up being `0`.  That `+` there isn't really *math*, it's just a type family, and GHC doesn't *understand* any logic therein.  All GHC knows is that `n + 1` is a type family application that can't be reduced, so there's no evidence that `n` is not `0`, so `Index` can't be reduced.

---

> If not, what are my alternatives?

Well, there's the one you don't like, which is to use `data Nat = Z | S Nat`.  There's no apparent math anymore, just constructors and pattern matching, and you don't even need to close the type family to make it work.

The next thing you can do is use a type-checker plugin that actually knows some math.  While I believe this is viable, I don't know of any plugins that actually do this.  Maybe someone else can suggest one, or maybe you can write your own.

The last option is to write some mathematical axioms yourself and use `unsafeCoerce` as your "proof".  It's far from elegant, but if it makes your library work the way you want, then go for it.

In this case, you could pretty easily write:

```hs
prf :: Index (a:v) (n + 1) -> Index v n
prf = unsafeCoerce
```

and have pretty high confidence nothing will go wrong.  Using the `constraints` library, you could also try writing something like this:

```hs
axiom1 :: forall a v n. Dict (Index (a:v) (n + 1) ~ Index v n)
axiom1 = unsafeCoerce $ Dict @()

prf :: forall a v n. Index (a:v) (n + 1) -> Index v n
prf = case axiom1 @a @v @n of
  Dict -> id
```

Here, our `axiom1` asserts that these two types are equivalent.  In `prf`, we extract that `Dict`, which gives us our evidence, so we can define `prf` as `id`.

Comment: Okay... is there any way I can create a singleton for `data Nat = Z | S Nat` that doesn't store the data in unary at runtime?

Comment: @NieDzejkob If you only use `Nat` at the type level then type erasure ensures that the data is not stored at run time period.

Comment: @ÉamonnOlive I am aware. However, I need to write a recursive algorithm that uses `SNat` or similar.

Comment: @NieDzejkob: The most frequent recommendation I see for a typechecker plugin for this is [ghc-typelits-natnormalise](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-natnormalise). I don’t know its limitations, but I believe it should handle this case.

Comment: @JonPurdy Thanks. It solves n + 1 - 1 :~: n, but the type family doesn't get resolved. Is there a way I can express the number being not equal zero in a way that Haskell will take into account when considering Index?

Comment: @NieDzejkob: Ah, right, that makes sense because of the same issue, that the type family doesn’t reduce…unfortunately, I don’t really know how to solve it. For a term-level *function* I would use a typeclass, but that doesn’t help here. You can’t use `TypeFamilyDependencies` to make it injective directly, although maybe it can be refactored to allow that. Or perhaps the way to do it is to explicitly convert between the packed `KnownNat` dictionary (in e.g. `SomeNat`) and unary Peano naturals, and just try to avoid reifying anything at runtime. This seems like a fundamental limitation. :/

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'm not sure what your use case is, but the "unsafeCoerce with axioms" method has served me well in the past for situations like this.  It feels inelegant, but if you set it up properly, it's really not so bad.